# Erro de ambiguidade depois de alterar resource (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou trabalhando em um projeto ASP.NET MVC faz meses. Ele é um sistema disponível em inglês e português, sendo o inglês o idioma padrão. Eu faço isso através do uso de Resources, e vinha funcionando sem problemas, veja imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, agora ao tentar adicionar uma nova String no **Translation.resx**, ao compilar dá erros de ambiguidade de classes.

> The namespace 'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations' already contains a
>   definition for 'Translation'

e

> Ambiguity between
>   'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations.Translation.ResourceManager' and
>   'VolunteerGames.Web.Translations.Translation.ResourceManager'

Notei que depois de inserir essa nova string, o visual studio criou outro arquivo chamado **Translation1.Designer.cs**. Esse arquivo também tem uma classe chamada **Translation**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então se eu excluir esse novo arquivo criado, eu consigo compilar, mas a nova string-resource que eu criei não é encontrada quando tento usar no controller.

Alguma ideia do que pode ter ocorrido ou está ocorrendo que fica criando esse arquivo **Translation1.Designer.cs** dando ambiguidade?

Comment: Está resposta está muito parecida com o que aconteceu com vc. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe66fbe7-50ef-4250-bbde-6ffc545bc929/ambiguity-between-projectpropertiesresourcesgradient-and?forum=Vsexpressvcs. Caso tenha dificuldade em inglês, traduz pelo crome mesmo, dá pra entender.

Comment: Como você criou esse arquivo novo?

Comment: Eu não criei. Ele foi criado automaticamente quando adicionei uma nova string no resx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como disse o Visual Studio crio o arquivo **Translation1.Designer.cs** e esse ficava dando confilito como **Translation.Designer.cs**. Eu apagava esse Translation1, mas dava erro de compilação e perdia as alteraçoes. Então apaguei o **Translation.Designer.cs** e tudo foi resolvido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]